# Angular 2 404 - Unable to read json file using http get

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I am new to angular and going through pluralsight tutorials, i am stuck at a point and not able to go further, my problem is like i have a json file products.json and i am trying to read from Http get method, the application throwing an exception on console which is mentioned below.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/products.json 404 (Not Found)
```

below is my app structure

[image: Structure of my application]

here is my ts code.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { IProduct } from "./product";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/Http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";


@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    private _productUrl: string = "../data/products/products.json";


    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getProducts():Observable< IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get("/api/products.json")
                    .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]>response.json())
                    .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    handleError(error: Response) {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'system error');
    }
}
```

Please let me know, if i am doing something wrong.
thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you put the URL (`http://localhost:4200/api/products.json`) directly in the browser's address bar (outside of angular)? Probably a 404 I am guessing.

Comment: Yeah exactly i got 404, i am new to angular not sure how its gonna work

Comment: My point was it has nothing to do with angular. If you can't get to the file from your browser using the address bar how will angular be able to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out-of-the-box functionality of Angular projects built with the CLI allows for files to be publicly accessible via the assets folder located at `/src/assets`.  You can configure your project to allow other locations to be publicly accessible by editing the file `angular-cli.json`.  Find the line `assets` and modify it in a way that allows access to the file(s) in question:

```
"assets": ["assets", "products.json","api/products.json"],
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no API that expose on `/api/products.json`, so you can't access this file on this url.

You can try to access the file directly, with :

```
this._http.get(_productUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CLI you need to add the api folder to the assets in the `angular-cli.json` file

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "api"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your products.json file to .\src\assets\api\products as the project angular CLI only allows to download content from asset using direct url.

```
private productUrl = 'assets/api/products/products.json';
```